# RequireComponent attribute like unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, game-engine

I'm currently developing a component based game engine in C# using GDI+ and have come to a point where some components rely on others.

I wish to create a RequireComponents attribute, which checks if the game object contains the required component (much like how unity does it)

I've never actually created a custom attribute before... so sorry if I sound stupid but I'm not sure how to approach it.

This is all I have so far haha:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameEngine.Components
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class RequireComponent : Attribute
    {
        public RequireComponent(Type type)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is missing from RequireComponent attribute that you would need to create your own?

Answer (score 0):

The rest depends completely on your library but I think that's pretty much all you need at Attribute level.

Just add a field to store the required type to be able to use it later.

```
Type componentType;
public Type ComponentType{
  get{ return componentType; }
}
```

Set it in the constructor.

Later, when you add a component to an entity...

```
// Returns whether the component is successfully added
public bool AddComponent(Component c){
  var attribute = 
    c.GetType().
    GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireComponent), true).
    FirstOrDefault() as RequireComponent;
  if (attribute != null)
  {
    // Check requirements
    if(!AlreadyHasComponent(requiredAttribute.ComponentType)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  // Requirements met: Add c
  return true;
}
```

You might want to make the field a `List<Type>` instead.

Or even give a look at existing ECS libraries for Unity.
There is one in particular I tried and like a lot: [Entitas](https://github.com/sschmid/Entitas-CSharp)